# Sphinx: how to show attributes as in scipy

Tags: python, format, python-sphinx, autodoc, sphinx-napoleon

Let's say we have the following module `testmodule.py` with a `TestClass` definition:

```py
"""This is a test module"""

class TestClass:
    """
    This is a simple description.

    Attributes
    ----------
    egg : int
        An egg. Should be from a chiken.
    animal : str
        The animal that laid the egg.

    """

    def __init__(self, egg, animal):
        self.animal = animal
        if self.is_chicken(animal):
            self.egg = egg
        else:
            self.egg = 0

    def is_chicken(self, animal):
        """Checks if the animal is a chicken.

        Returns True if it is, False otherwise

        Parameters
        ----------
        animal : str
            An animal that lays eggs

        Returns
        -------
        bool
            True if `animal` is chicken. False otherwise.
        """
        if animal == 'chicken':
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Using Sphinx 3.5.4 with `autodoc` and `napoleon` extensions, and `pydata_sphinx_theme` as the theme in `conf.py`, I get the doc for the class shown below.

I used `.. automodule:: testmodule` in a test.rst file, that index.rst references, with `:member:` and `:show-inheritance:`.

[image]

But I would actually like something more like Scipy has for the attributes.

[image]

The closest I can get is by setting `napoleon_use_ivar = True` in `conf.py`, which outputs something close, except that we get "Variables" instead of "Attributes" and the definition is inlined with the attribute name and type.

[image]

Comment: By digging around the matplotlib github pages, I figured out I have to use `numpydoc` instead of `sphinx.ext.napoleon`. But I get a warning from `autosummary` for "stub file not found". And have to check my `autosummary_generate` setting.

Answer (score 1):

To get the desired output, instead of using `sphinx.ext.napoleon`, use `numpydoc`. It has to be loaded after `sphinx.ext.autodoc`, according to the [Matplotlib conf.py](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/v3.5.2/doc/conf.py) file.

Additionally, since no summary table of the methods is desired, simply set `numpydoc_show_class_members` to `False`.

I was having another issue where multiple descriptions for parameters and attributes appeared. Turns out, it's because I was documenting them by hand in the class docstring but also using type-hints (for static type checking with `pyright`) and `autodoc_typehints` was set to `document`. This wasn't an issue when using sphinx napoleon, because it is implemented according to this [sphinx napoleon RTD](https://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_numpy.html). But there is an [open issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpydoc/issues/196) in `numpydoc` since 2019 to allow for type annotations. So the workaround is to set `autodoc_typehints` either to `none` or to `signature`.

In summary, in the `conf.py` file set:

```py
extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
    'numpydoc',  # needs to be loaded *after* autodoc
]
# NOTE: numpydoc automatically loads autosummary.
numpydoc_show_class_members = False
autodoc_typehints = "none"
```

And we get:

[image]

Now I just have to figure out how to keep the new lines between the attribute type and its description in pdf documents...